# Python going to new page by chagning url number

Tags: python

hi i need to make this python code loop page from 1 until 5

('https://test.com/index/1')

if their any way with selenium that will be cool <3
am new it python

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests
import json
import csv
import time

html = urlopen('https://test.com/index/1')
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
images = bs.find_all('img', {'src':re.compile('.jpg')})
for image in images: 

    print(image['src'].split('/')[-1].split('_')[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop on range of numbers add use them as parameter

```
for i in range(1, 6):
    html = urlopen(f'https://test.com/index/{i}')
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    images = bs.find_all('img', {'src': re.compile('.jpg')})
    for image in images:
        print(image['src'].split('/')[-1].split('_')[0])
```

Comment: this method didn't work  for i in range(1, 6): it show only number 1 

+ only print page number 1 any help with that or some thing like selenium ?

Comment: @متعبالعتيبي Did you use all my code or did you just take the first line? You need to use the number as parameter, in your code it's fixed as 1.

Comment: yeah i did use all the code didn't work sorry am new it python

Comment: maybe can you give me example ?
i did used @Guy code work but didn't loop for pages + only print page number 1 
like this code 
```python for i in range(1, 6):
    html = urlopen(f'https://test.com/index/1{i}') 
```
should i put number one like this ?          ^

Answer (score 0):

It is mostly same as @Guy, but you can do it this way too.

```
for num in range(1, 6):
    html = urlopen(f'https://test.com/index/%s'%num)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    images = bs.find_all('img', {'src': re.compile('.jpg')})
    for image in images:
        print(image['src'].split('/')[-1].split('_')[0])
```